# How to redirect an user to a specific webpage after Google Sign In with Redirect in Firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

The nature of the sign-in flow with Google/Facebook is that after we login in the redirected page of Google, it comes back to our website's sign-in page.

The following code runs when the Google/Facebook login button is clicked:
`fire.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);`

So, my current approach is that I check the Firebase user object using the onAuthStateChanged() function. If the user state is populated, I render a  component, else if it is null, I render the  component.

```
{user ? (
    <Home />
  ) : (
    <Signup />
)}
```

But the problem is that after logging in using Google or Facebook, the  component is **showing for some time (maybe 1-2 secs)** and then rendering the  component.

I want to render the  component immediately after I login using Google redirect. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

google and facebook login system are asynchronous in nature so you shoud you async await method inside you code.

Answer (score 0):

You should show a full loading state in the login screen when clicking on the signin button

So when the authentication starts show the user a loader,

and if fails stop the loader

you could do something like

```
  if (authUser === undefined || isLoading) {
   return <AuthLoader />;
  }
  return <LoginComponentContents/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use for all authentication methods the `onAuthStateChanged` listener in `auth`. That way it doesn't matter what method you use. It will give you the `user` if someon is logged in and `null` if not. The code looks like this:

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

Use that listener to define the state of your auth (if a user is signed in or not). You can also persiste the data in your state menegement to awoid flickering on page reloads. You can use the same method for email/password login. That way you have a single and simple solution for all Firebasse authentication methods.

For the time you await the Google or other provider redirect login I would recommend to set a loading flag and show a circular loading indicator. The login could always fail. I would not recommend to show pages that require a signed in user untill you get the response from `authStateChanged` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

For Firebase v9 and above:

If using an AuthContext file, you can define your signInWithRedirect and getRedirectResult functions. Then, import those functions into your Signup page.

AuthContext:

```
    //Log in user with provider. Redirects away from your page.
 async function loginGoogle() {
    await signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
  return
}

//Checks for provider login result, then navigates
async function getRedirect(){
  const result = await getRedirectResult(auth);
    if (result) {
      navigate('/')
    }
}
```

In your Signup page, call the login function on button click

```
    //Sign in with Google.
async function handleGoogleLogin(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    try {
        setError('')
        await loginGoogle()
    } catch(error) {
        setError('Failed to log in')
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

Then, just place the getRedirect() function in your Signup component. This function will run when the page reloads from the google redirect, thus sending your user to the desired page.

```
 //Checks for Google Login result.
getRedirect();
```

For me, it only worked when using this 2-step approach because when the provider redirect occurs, the async function appears to not finished as expected. So loginWithRedirect in one step, then getRedirectResult and navigate in a second step.